# how to apply pagination in jquery on dynamic data coming through database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pagination

I am fetching data from my database through ajax.

I have thousands of data in my table.

I am trying to add pagination below the table.

I am using #Easy Large Table Pagination Plugin With jQuery - Paginator for that purpose. This plugin is working on static content but when I apply in a dynamic table it is not working.

Is there any other query plugin through which I can achieve my goal?

Comment: what have you tried so far? show some code and also read this article https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/

Comment: have a look at data tables - https://datatables.net/ it pretty much does everything.  I would delete this question as it is off topic and will mostly likely get downvoted